# react-native run-android error : gradlew.bat on Atom

Tags: android, react-native, atom-editor, gradlew

I have a problem when I try to run my react-native program on Atom

I got this error :

```
Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

[image]

What I am supposed to do?

Comment: Try ```cd android && ./gradlew clean``` and run again.

Comment: It's try and didn't work

Comment: try npx react-native run-android

Comment: I think i get an error with my path. 

I have this error: `error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of emulator -list-avds`

But i think that my path is fine. But he cant lunch emulator.

Can you add me or discord please? 

ID: greatfullbon#9079